# Generating only "Classes" section (i.e. no "Files") in phpdoc

Tags: phpdoc

Is there a way to turn off the "Files" section in the menu of phpdoc's output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could just edit the template files, and comment out (or just delete) those sections. Granted, it doesn't stop it from generating the actual files, but my menu isn't all cluttered anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No.  I don't think this has been requested before, so you could make a feature request for it [1].  However, given that the Files organizational structure is fairly core to all the output templates, that might be a difficult feature to implement.

[1] -- http://pear.php.net/bugs/search.php?package_name[]=PhpDocumentor&cmd=display